# Button Group doesn't stay aligned with nav items due to Float property

Tags: html, css, buttongroup

Recently I have been implementing a Button Group to (eventualy) select the language for a website that Im developing but I have runned into 2 problems:

1 – The Button group needs “float: left” for the buttons to be joined and the thing is… the floating is making the button group stay out of alignment with the other nav items.

2 – Another problem is that there is some sort of property in the nav that is making my button group having this huge rectangular padding, which shouldn’t happen… I have already checked the Chrome Inspector and I haven’t found anything and I am getting frustrated as hell with this.

So to sum it up, I want my nav to look like this:
[image]

And Here is how I implemented my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
  });
});

// Scrolling Effect

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 4em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
  ;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*Button Group Starts here*/

div.btn-group a {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* transparent background */
  border: 1px solid white;
  /* transparent border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  padding: 7px 7px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.selected-lang {
  background-color: #c1b882 !important;
  color: white !important;
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.btn-group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.btn-group a:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.btn-group a:hover {
  background-color: #c1b882;
  color: white;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
  }
  nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
  }
  .showing {
    max-height: 34em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- 
      awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>

    <nav>

      <div class="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="logo">
        LOGO
      </div>

      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a href="#" class="selected-lang">EN</a>
              <a href="index.html">PT</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be really apreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `float:left` property and instead of this use `position:relative;` in last element of button-group it will not cause any issue in small and big viewpoint.

I have to change your CSS a bit and it may work for you. :)

find code below:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 4em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: black;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/*Button Group Starts here*/

div.btn-group a {
background-color: transparent; /* transparent background */
border: 1px solid white; /* transparent border */
color: white; /* White text */
cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
padding: 7px 7px;
margin: 0;
}

.selected-lang{
background-color: #c1b882 !important;
color: white !important;
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
clear: both;
}

.btn-group a:not(:last-child) {
border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
position: relative;
    right: -5px;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group a:hover {
background-color: #c1b882;
color: white;
}


.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

  .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
  }

  nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
        background: #000;
  }

  nav.black ul {
        background: #000;
  }

  .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
  }

  nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: center;
  }

  .menu-icon {
        display: block;
  }

}
```